# Java: Logical operation of boolean with null

Tags: java

Lets say I have a hash map like this:

```
private Map<someObject, Boolean> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
```

And I have two methods like this:

```
public void methodOne(key) {
    if (hashMap.get(key) == null || !hashMap.get(key)) {
       //do something
       hashMap.put(key, true);
    }
}
```

and

```
public void methodtwo(key) {
    if (hashMap.get(key) != null && hashMap.get(key)) {
       //do something else
       hashMap.put(key, false);
    }
}
```

My code seems to be working, but I am wondering the logical operation that I am doing in the if statements are valid and wether there is a better way to do it?

The other thing I am wondering is, what would be the result for the following logical operations:

- `null || true`
- `null || false`
- `null && true`
- `null && false`

Comment: The usual incorporation of null into boolean logic has `null || true == true`, `null || false == null`, `null && true == null`, `null && false == false`

Comment: Nothing wrong with your code, "better way" in this case is a matter of opinion. The result of the logical operations at the end of your question is a compilation error.

Comment: @khelwood How so? Is SQL more "usual" than C?

Comment: You cannot combine `null` with `true` or `false`. `null` can have many meanings, and such operations should not be performed. Java explicitly removed such operations from C/C++.

Comment: @Oleg I was describing the rules I know according to [three-valued logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic?wprov=sfla1). If you know a better set of defined rules, go ahead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [Map::getOrDefault](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#getOrDefault-java.lang.Object-V-). See below:

```
public void methodOne(key) {
    if (!hashMap.getOrDefault(key, false)) {
       //do something
       hashMap.put(key, true);
    }
}
```

and

```
public void methodtwo(key) {
    if (hashMap.getOrDefault(key, false)) {
       //do something else
       hashMap.put(key, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Great answer because it doesn't assume any property of `null`, it simply replaces the missing value with a default one, in this case false.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
public void methodOne(key) {
  if (!Boolean.TRUE.equals(hashMap.get(key))) {
     //do something
     hashMap.put(key, true);
  }
}

public void methodtwo(key) {
  if (Boolean.TRUE.equals(hashMap.get(key))) {
     //do something
     hashMap.put(key, false);
  }
}
```

Comment: That hides the fact that `null` can be returned and completely goes against the principle of least surprise. It's a ugly hack and the next programmer may try and replace it with `Boolean.FALSE.equals(...)` and see the code fail horribly, usually in the field after testing.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use optional

```
public void methodOne(key) {
    if (!Optional.ofNullable(hashMap.get(key)).orElse(false)) {
       //do something
       hashMap.put(key, true);
    }
}

public void methodtwo(key) {
    if (Optional.ofNullable(hashMap.get(key)).orElse(false)) {
       //do something else
       hashMap.put(key, false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

> Are the if statements valid and is there a better way to do it?

Yes and yes. See [answer by Stepan Kolesnik](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61261882/5221149).

> What would be the result for the following logical operations:
>
> - `null || true`
> - `null || false`
> - `null && true`
> - `null && false`

*Truth table*

```
                  null    false    true
null || true      yes     no       yes
null || false     yes     yes      no       methodOne: set true
null && true      ERROR   no       no
null && false     ERROR   no       no
!null && true     no      no       yes      methodtwo: set false
!null && false    no      yes      no
```

As you can see, in essence, `methodOne` is an unconditional `key = true`, while `methodtwo` leaves `null` unchanged, otherwise sets `key = false`.